# Updating MySQL field beforeunload

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, onbeforeunload

I'm working on a CMS to allow users to access and classify records in MySQL database. I have created a user login system for this CMS. I am trying to program a lock out function that will monitor when a record is being viewed so that no other users can access this record. This is to prevent multiple users from trying to write to the same record at the same time.

So far this part works fairly well. When they access the record I update the field "in_use" within the MySQL database for that particular record to show that it is being viewed. When they have submitted the form with the classification for the record it, I update the field "in_use" to show that it is no longer being viewed.

The problem I have is when the user closes the browser without submitting the form, or when they navigate away from the page.

I have been trying to use AJAX to run an update on the beforeunload event, but it has not been working.

***** readRecord.php*****

```
<h1>Analyze</h1>

//PHP include that contains functions for php queries to the MySQL database.

<?php
    include 'core/database/record_functions.php';
?>

//Form to search MySQL database by Case Number and Button to manually release a record that is in_use.

<form action="" method="post">

<p id="case_search">Search records by Case Number: <input type="text" id="case_num_field" name="case_num">

<input type="text" name="in_use" id="in_use" readonly="readonly" hidden="hidden" value="1">

<input type="text" name="user" id="user" readonly="readonly" hidden="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>">

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Select" id="case_num_submit">

<input type="Submit" name="release record" value="Release the current record" onclick="<?php update_in_use($_SESSION['case_num'], 0); ?>">
</p>

</form>

//Includes for jQuery library and AJAX code for automatically releasing the record on page navigation or close.

<script type="text/javascript" src="core/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxBridge.js"></script>

... code continues for reading records
... when the form is submitted update_in_use is called again to set the value to 0
```

***** ajaxBridge.js *****

```
// This code is supposed to run the query on releaseVariable.php to update the in_use field to 0 on the beforeunload event.

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event){
   if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
   {
    xmlHttp.open("POST", "releaseVariable.php", true);
    xmlHttp.send();
    event.returnValue = "Hey it worked!";
   }
   event.returnValue = "Hey it failed!";
   });
```

***** releaseVariable.php *****

```
// This simply runs the update_in_use function to set the in_use field to 0 for this particular case.

<?php
include 'core/init.php';
include 'read_record.php';
protect_page();

update_in_use($_SESSION['case_num'], 0);

?>
```

Am I going about this the right way? If not how do I address this issue instead?

If this is a good method, where did I go astray with the code?

Comment: I also just realized I forgot to add the else to my if statement in the ajaxBridge.js file ... ooops

Comment: When reviewing the bottom half of readRecord.php, I found that I had unwittingly assigned two inputs with the same name and id "in_use". Maybe this is causing the value to be set regardless of when I attempt to use the ajax update. Although, it seems that it would still run afterwards and release the record.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to abandon this approach and use php SESSION variables instead.